# Custom Ribbon XML Tab not showing in WORD VSTO Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

I followed this [MSDN Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) to create a `WORD 2010` **VSTO AddIn** Tab. I am using `VS2015 Community Edition`. When I run the app in Visual Studio, it opens the Word document but the Tab does not show up in WORD (as claimed by the testing steps of the turorial). So, I cannot test the AddIn.

However, I can see the above AddIn in the COM Add-Ins window of the WORD as enabled - as shown in the image below. Also, when I place  break point in the following procedure, I can see this procedure is called successfully. **Note**: I followed the tutorial word by word by copying/pasting the code, project name etc. So, I changed nothing from the tutorial.

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
     return new MyRibbon();
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: The **MyRibbon.xml** is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">  
        <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">  
            <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"  
                 screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"  
                 supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>  
            <button id="tableButton" label="Insert Table"  
                 screentip="Table" onAction="OnTableButton"  
                 supertip="Inserts a table at the cursor location."/>  
        </group>  
      </tab> 
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**UPDATE 2**: After reading comment by `@dotNET` below, I think the the problem seems to be my WORD doc missing the built-in `ADD-INS`. How can I display the `ADD-INS` tab? From the customize tabs option in WORD I don't see that tab as shown in the image below. Where should I look?

[image]

Comment: Can u share your ribbon XML?

Comment: @dotNET Sure, I just added ribbon XML file content in **UPDATE** section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your buttons will be added to the built-in `ADD-INS` tab using the code you have provided. If you want your own custom tab, do not use `idMso`. Instead define your `<tab>` node like this:

```
<tab id="tabMyVeryOwnCustomTab" label="TRUMPED">
  <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">  
        <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"  
             screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"  
             supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>  
        <button id="tableButton" label="Insert Table"  
             screentip="Table" onAction="OnTableButton"  
             supertip="Inserts a table at the cursor location."/>  
  </group>  
</tab>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. How do I find `ADD-INS` tab. I'm not seeing it in `WORD 2010`?

Comment: Should be there by default. You can always display it by using Customize Ribbon tab in Options dialog.

Comment: I've added an **UPDATE 2**. I'm not seeing `ADD-INS` tab in the Ribbon Tab Options dialog as shown in image 2 above.

Comment: Strange. Can u try Reset button in the Customize dialog?

Comment: Reset button did not help either. But, I've marked your response as an Answer since you provided a workaround while the issue, as you pointed out, seems to be related to my  Office 2010 installation, for some reason, is missing the default `ADD-INS`tab - and hence for that new issue I'll create a new post.

Comment: AFAIK the add-ins tab exists to 'ribbonize' add-ins that use commandbars. As it doesn't have any commands of its own it doesn't show in the All Tabs list of available commands.

Comment: @m4o_tim: Not so. Firstly it should at least exist in Customize dialog where we could turn it on and off. VSTO by default places our command buttons (whether you use XML or Ribbon Designer) in the Add-ins tab, as evident in OP's post.

Comment: @dotNET: It does exist in the Customize dialog, but the OP is looking for it in wrong place. The Customize dialog has two columns. The one in the screenshot from the OP is the left column which shows the commands that can be added to the ribbon. As the Add-ins tab doesn't have any commands it doesn't appear in this list. It does appear in the column to the right of the one in the screenshot which shows the available tabs that can be shown/hidden.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in Excel 2016.  New tabs don't appear in the Customize Ribbon or on the Add-Ins tab.